# x86 AND instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, logical-operators

In x86 64-bit, I have the following instruction:

```
and $0xf, %eax
```

The contents of %eax before and after remains 4. How is that possible? ANDing `100 & 1111` should result in `1100` which is 12, and not 4.

Comment: "ANDing 100 & 1111 should result in 1100" No, it should result in `100`. Which the instruction computes, so all is well.

Comment: Maybe you meant `add`, not `and`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since when is `0100 & 1111 = 1100`?

```
  0100 = 4
& 1111 = 15
------
  0100 = 4
```

Answer (score 9):

Think of `100` as `0100` and you can see that `0100 & 1111` is clearly `0100`.

Answer (score 7):

Nope - you're making a mistake.  100 & 1111 = 100.